# Mapbox: Hide traversed route after maneuver

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am curious if it is possible to adjust the route after a maneuver like you can see in this video from the Mapbox website: https://www.mapbox.com/assets/use-cases-navigation-sdk-272b22ac06adc9a4275dcc13624112d8.mp4
Goal is to hide the route which has already been traversed.

I am using the mapbox navigation android sdk but didn't find anything in the docs.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for checking out the Android Navigation SDK!  You're correct, unfortunately we currently don't have APIs to support this use-case.

If you'd like, it would be great if you cut a ticket for feature request with a `.gif` of this video: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/issues

Thanks again and let us know if you have any other questions.